# Need prompt help with using AWK / sort / uniq to remove lines that have identical values in first column from a simple text file

Tags: sorting, awk, uniq

I have a bunch of text files with the following contents in column1 and column2 (separated by a space):

address0 data0

address1 data1

.

.

.

addressN dataN

All data values are unique (random), but some address values are repeated. How do I use AWK / sort / uniq to remove the lines that have addresses that are already specified?

Basically, there should be no duplicate addresses in the text file, no matter what the associated data is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort -k1 your_file | awk '{ if ($1 != last_address_seen) {print $0; last_address_seen=$1}}'`

Comment: it ends up outputing 0 lines. :-(

Comment: this actually worked when i used gawk. i think it was some cygwin issue. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    $1 in seen {next}
    {print; seen[$1] = 1}
' file ...
```

Comment: This has the advantage of retaining the original order of the lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -k1 -u your_file > outputfile
```

Most unix sort commands will support -u option which will Keep only the first of two lines that compare equal on all keys.